# grep substring which is a variable having prefix dot

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I am having an array which would have values as `namespace=(example examples-ixx)`
I need to iterate through this array using for loop where in i'll be storing `example` string in variable called ns. Below is the content of file which I would be looking into.

```
http://example-service-v2.example-ixx:8080/actuator/info
http://example-service-v2.example:8080/actuator/info
```

I tried with following combinations however it didn't work
`grep -w ".$ns" filename`
`grep -w "\.$ns" filename`
`fgrep -w ".$ns" filename`
`fgrep -w "\.$ns" filename`

I want to grep exact string which is currently assigned to variable $ns. Not more not less. Can someone help me with this one.

Comment: Can you please add to your question sufficient source data and code to allow us to replicate the results you're finding problematic?  What kind of variable stores the substrings? What is producing the URLs? What sets `$ns` and what exactly is it set to? Try to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that folks can produce answers with some confidence that they're actually addressing the problem you're having.

Comment: Changed problem statement for better understanding.

Comment: Well, as you see with your own solution which you posted, you can't use `-w`. I also thought to suggest `-P`, but since it is said on the grep man page that -P is still considered experimental, I prefer to use -E, if it also does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Per your question, let's set an array:

```
declare -a namespace=(
  example
  example-ixx
)
```

Then you can step through your array, running a `grep` for each element. For example:

```
for ns in "${namespace[@]}"; do
  printf '%s> %s\n' "$ns" "$(grep "\.$ns:" input.txt)"
done
```

Note that this does not protect against the possibility of multiple entries in your list of URLs. I don't know if that matters, of course.

Alternately, you could construct a regex from your array content:

```
grep -E "\.($(IFS="|$IFS"; printf '%s\n' "${namespace[*]}")):" input.txt
```

This results in a single stream of output rather than processing one line per array element, and might be complicated by the inclusion of regex special characters in your source array.

Note that with both of these solutions, we wrap what we're searching for in `.` and `:`, per the sample input in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `-w` is ruining your day. From the man-page, describing the -w option:

*Select only those lines containing matches that form  whole  words.        The  test  is  that  the  matching  substring must either be at the           beginning of the  line,  or  preceded  by  a  non-word  constituent character.*

If you have a string *v2.example:*, the character in front of the dot is *2*, which is a word character and hence does not match. You could of course write

```
grep -F ".$ns" ....
```

but this would also catch *.exampleabc*.

As long as your variable `ns` does not contain characters which have a special meaning in a regular expression, you could go with

```
grep -E "[.]$ns\\>" ....
```

because `\>` matches a word boundary. However, if `ns` does contain such a character, this would not work. You could improve it by

```
grep -E "[.]\\Q$ns\\E\\>" ....
```

because what's between `\Q` and `\E` is taken literally, but this solution is not perfect either: If `ns` itself contains these special escapes, you would get funny results.

Technically, one would need to escape all regex characters inside `ns`, but doing this just with the tools of POSIX shell, is something I wouldn't even force to let my enemy do. If you really need a solution which works in the general case, it's perhaps easier to do the grepping with a small script written in a languages like Perl or Ruby, where you have built-in functions for escaping a regexp.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with -w switch. Cause that's the requirement when i grep for `example` it should only give me the lines containing example and when i grep for `example-ixx` it should only give me the lines containing example-ixx

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue using below grep command.

```
grep -P "((?<=^)|(?<=\s))$var(?=(\s|$))"
```

Comment: This would blow up if, for instance, you want to search for a literal string `exa{5}` and set `var="exa{5}". This is the same problem which I have discussed in my answer.